# Particles emit even though emission is disabled

Tags: unity, particles

I have created a basic particle system which is a single burst around a sphere.

I have a script that disables this emission upon `Start`.

If I don't disable the emission, then the particles continuously emit in bursts.

However when I disable the emission, it does not completely prevent particles from being emitted. There is still a single burst at the beginning.

Here is how it looks with emission disabled:

[image]

Here is the script which is setting `emission.enabled = false`. This is attached to the sphere and the particle system is a child of the sphere.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BalloonPop : MonoBehaviour
{
    public new Renderer renderer;
    public ParticleSystem emitter;
    public float explosionTime = 0.5f;

    private ParticleSystem.EmissionModule emission;

    void Start() {
        if (!renderer) { renderer = GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>(); };
        if (!emitter) { emitter = GetComponentInChildren<ParticleSystem>(); }
        emission = emitter.emission;
        renderer.enabled = true;
        emission.enabled = false; // <===================================== this
    }
}
```

All I want to do right now is to make it not emit any particles at all.Then I'll add an event to re-enable the emission, but that's not the issue I'm asking about here. I also tried `emitter.enableEmission = false`, which is deprecated, and it didn't work.

Here is the particle system in the inspector:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that I needed to disable Play On Awake in the ParticleSettings settings.

Comment: You can accept your own answers for the question - make sure you give yourself props!

Comment: @Tom'Blue'Piddock I know, but you can't accept until 2 days later :/